# How to pass parameters to the cursor and fetch the records from the two tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

In a loop, use a cursor to retrieve the deptNumber and the deptName
from the “Department” table, pass the deptNumber to a ref cursor to retrieve
the employees who belong to that deptNumber from the table named
“Employee”. How to pass parameters to the cursor and fetch the records from the Employee table?

```
    set serveroutput on;
declare
cursor dept_cursor(deptid hr.departments.department_id%type) is 
select department_id, department_name from hr.departments where department_id = deptid;
deptno hr.departments.department_id%type;
deptname hr.departments.department_name%type;

cursor emp_cursor(deptid hr.departments.department_id%type) is
select employee_id, first_name, salary, job_id from hr.employees where department_id = deptid;
empno hr.employees.employee_id%type;
empname hr.employees.first_name%type;
sal hr.employees.salary%type;
jobid hr.employees.job_id%type;

begin
open dept_cursor(10);
loop
fetch dept_cursor into deptno, deptname;
exit when dept_cursor%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line('Department no : '|| deptno||' Department name : '||deptname);
end loop;
close dept_cursor;
open emp_cursor(10);
loop
fetch emp_cursor into empno, empname, sal, jobid;
exit when emp_cursor%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line('Employee no : '|| empno||' Employee name : '||empname ||'Employee Salary :' ||sal||' Job :'||jobid);
end loop;
close emp_cursor;

end;
```

Comment: Done modification in the tables for fetching result from one table. Though records to be fetched from another table is pending.

Comment: set serveroutput on;
declare
cursor dept_cursor(deptid hr.departments.department_id%type) is 
select department_id, department_name from hr.departments where department_id = deptid;
dept_rec hr.departments%rowtype;
begin
open dept_cursor(10);
loop
fetch dept_cursor into dept_rec;
exit when dept_cursor%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line('Department no : '||dept_rec.department_id||' Department name : '||dept_rec.department_name);
end loop;
close dept_cursor;
end;

Comment: The SQL clients you are using (Oracle SQL Developer or PL/SQL Developer) are completely irrelevant to the question . So why add those tags?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your tables so I used Scott's sample schema. Read comments within code (and don't post your own code as a comment; I guess you already saw that it is unreadable).

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_rc      sys_refcursor;
  3    -- variables which will be used to display ref cursor's values
  4    l_empno   emp.empno%type;
  5    l_ename   emp.ename%type;
  6    l_sal     emp.sal%type;
  7  begin
  8    -- loop through all departments, using cursor FOR loop
  9    for cur_r in (select deptno from dept) loop
 10
 11      -- fetch employees (for that department) into a ref cursor
 12      open l_rc for select empno, ename, sal
 13                    from emp
 14                    where deptno = cur_r.deptno;
 15
 16      -- display what's being fetched
 17      dbms_output.put_line('Department ' || cur_r.deptno);
 18      loop
 19        fetch l_rc into l_empno, l_ename, l_sal;
 20        exit when l_rc%notfound;
 21        dbms_output.put_line('  ' || l_empno ||': '|| rpad(l_ename, 10, ' ') || l_sal);
 22      end loop;
 23    end loop;
 24  end;
 25  /
```

which results in

```
Department 10
- 7782: CLARK     2450
- 7839: KING      5000
- 7934: MILLER    1300
Department 20
- 7369: SMITH     800
- 7566: JONES     2975
- 7788: SCOTT     3000
- 7876: ADAMS     1100
- 7902: FORD      3000
Department 30
- 7499: ALLEN     1600
- 7521: WARD      1250
- 7654: MARTIN    1250
- 7698: BLAKE     2850
- 7844: TURNER    1500
- 7900: JAMES     950
Department 40

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems very complex. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Complex? What's complex about it? It does what you asked for. Uses the cursor to retrieve departments and passes it (a department) to ref cursor which returns desired result.